# how to use median as a analytic function (oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, median

Can you explain why the following works:

```
select recdate,avg(logtime) 
over 
(ORDER BY recdate rows between 10 preceding and 0 following) as logtime 
from v_download_times;
```

and the following doesn’t

```
select recdate,median(logtime)
over 
(ORDER BY recdate rows between 10 preceding and 0 following) as logtime
 from v_download_times;
```

(median instead of avg)

I get an **ORA-30487** error.

and I would be grateful for a workaround.

Comment: May be you can try:  select median(logtime)
over 
(ORDER BY recdate rows between 10 preceding and 0 following) as logtime
 from v_download_times;

Comment: ORA-30487 is for issues related to ORDER BY.

Comment: As far as I understand MEDIAN sorts input data by nature. There is no need to specify ordering. Especially when you want to order MEDIAN's input by some other column

Answer (score 2):

The error message is `ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here`.  And sure enough, if we consult the [documentation for the MEDIAN function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions099.htm#SQLRF51518) it says:

> "You can use MEDIAN as an analytic function. You can specify only the
>   query_partition_clause in its OVER clause."

Answer (score 1):

But it is not redundant if you only want to take it from a certain number of rows preceding the current one.
A way around may be limiting your data set just for the median purpose, like

```
select 
median(field) over (partition by field2) 
from ( select * from dataset 
        where period_back between 0 and 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

MEDIAN doesn't allow an ORDER BY clause. As APC points out in his answer, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions099.htm#SQLRF51518) tells us we can only specify the query_partition_clause.

ORDER BY is redundant as we're looking for the central value -- it's the same regardless of order.